# "Should" the roku video node be created in task thread always?

Tags: video, roku, brightscript

The video node can be created in both render thread & task node thread. Is there a mandate on video node to be created only in "task node" thread?

From the definition of render thread, it says that render thread must be used to create UI elements & any blocking operations can be moved to task node thread.

So, my question is if i'm creating a video player application, then video player controls & ui elements can be created in render thread & task node thread should have the video url loading, event listeners, button behaviors, player behaviors etc in task node thread. Am i right?

Comment: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/SceneGraph+Threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the opposite, you should not create a Video node (or any renderable node) in a task thread. Even though you're able to create a Video node in a task thread, those nodes are owned by the render thread, so you will be triggering very expensive rendezvous operations.

From the [documentation](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/SceneGraph+Threads#SceneGraphThreads-RenderableNode(Group)Objects):

> You should generally not create renderable node objects in a Task node
>   thread. The rendezvous mechanism will be required to create and
>   operate on those node objects. Every field set or get operation on
>   such nodes will require a full rendezvous, and this could impact the
>   performance of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alejandro.So, in case of video applications, what task needs to be asynchronous so that they can be performed in a task thread?

Comment: @KedarNath - If it's a video app, you'll probably have to make some API requests to get the stream urls, for that, you'll have to use `roUrlTransfer`, which can only be created on a Task/Main thread. Anything else will depend on your app requirements, but usually most of the time you'll be using task threads just for network requests.

Comment: Your facts are right - but your advice is wrong. Can create Video from any thread. Doing this on task thread is not likely to be a problem, unless doing excessive amount of access to its fields

Comment: @NasBanov My facts are my advice - if my facts are right how can my advice be wrong ? The question is not about if you can or can't, is about if you "should", and you should not; is explicitly mentioned in the docs. Creating a Video node (or any renderable node) in a task thread takes significantly more time than just creating it in the render thread; that's a problem. If you then plan to also access the node from the task thread is around 40ms-100ms per access depending on the device, I think that's a problem and also should you.

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla: Thank you. It took a bit of time to understand threading, however, i now understand and your answer was helpful in moving forward with my app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla - okay, since you asked for it - your facts are wrong too; only your link to doco is right. Here are my facts: creating 32 Video nodes (Premiere @ rOS 8.1) on render thread is 1250ms, same on main/task is 1420ms - that is a meager 14% overhead. Cross-threads, node field access () is ~17ms on all devices, not 30-100ms. Measure first, draw general conclusions later.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can create Video node on any thread you please. Consider the warning in previous answer that since visual objects are always owned by render threat, there will some delay setting/getting fields - but if that does not affect adversely your app, don't worry where to create the Video

Comment: _"there will some delay setting/getting fields"_ - that's exactly how **adversely** affects your app. You are basically saying _"Yeah, it will be slower, but don't worry about it"_ - not a great advice in my opinion.

Comment: Correct, i am saying "Yeah, it will be slower, but don't worry about it". i am also saying you don't need Ferrari to drive to work. You could but don't insist everyone else should do so too. Do worry about it when facing frequent, repetitive get/set of fields.